# Node title does not update

Tags: database, updating

I wanted to add a word in front of the title for certain nodes.
So I run an update sql statement on nodes table. The result can be seen in the attached image.
[image: Result after updating the table]

I empty the cache (flush all) but my new titles still do not appear on the website.
Should I update in a different place in database also? Do I have to do something else to see the new titles?

Thanks in advance for helping me out with this !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure you have to update "node_revision" too.

https://www.drupal.org/node/320614

> Note that the node_revisions table in the database will always have one record associated with each record in the node table, which it keeps track of as the current revision. This will happen even if you do not have revisions enabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort. I just run an update statement and it fixed the problem. No flush caching necessary. Thanks again.